# Adjusting data labels position with facet_grid in ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, plyr, facet

I have this example in R:

Packages

```
install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)

install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

install.packages("ggthemes")
library(ggthemes)
```

Here is my code:

```
    uf <- c("AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AM","AM","AM",
"AM","AM","AM","AM","AM")

    da <- c("Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada","Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada","Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada","Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada")

    tr <- c(97,99,90.5,78.6,3,1,9.5,21.4,97.2,99.1,96.8,98.7,2.8,0.9,3.2,1.3)

    resposta <- c("resposta","resposta","resposta","resposta","não resposta","não resposta","não resposta","não resposta","resposta","resposta","resposta","resposta", 
"não resposta","não resposta","não resposta","não resposta")

    taxa <- data.frame(uf, da, tr,resposta)

######_Adjusting data labels position_###############
   taxa <- ddply(taxa, .(da), transform, pos = cumsum(tr) - (0.5 * tr)) # Ajusta a posição

   g1 <- ggplot()+ geom_bar(aes(y = tr, x = da, fill = resposta), data = taxa, 
                          stat="identity") +
                facet_wrap(~uf) +
                geom_text(data=taxa, aes(x = da, y = pos, label = tr), size=4) + 
                theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.direction="horizontal", 
                 legend.title = element_blank())

   g1
```

Producing this figure:
[Question for dependencia with facet for uf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07CmO.png)

I would like to produce this figure with all values within the bars. And the y-axis to 100

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tidied your code a bit and used `ifelse` to determine the correct position of the labels.

```
Library(ggplot2)

uf <- c("AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AM","AM","AM",
        "AM","AM","AM","AM","AM")

da <- c("Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada","Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada","Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada","Federal", "Estadual", "Municipal", "Privada")

tr <- c(97,99,90.5,78.6,3,1,9.5,21.4,97.2,99.1,96.8,98.7,2.8,0.9,3.2,1.3)

resposta <- c("resposta","resposta","resposta","resposta","não resposta","não resposta","não resposta","não resposta","resposta","resposta","resposta","resposta", 
              "não resposta","não resposta","não resposta","não resposta")

taxa <- data.frame(uf, da, tr,resposta)

######_Adjusting data labels position_###############

taxa$pos <- ifelse(taxa$tr > 50, taxa$tr / 2, 100 -  taxa$tr / 2)

ggplot(taxa, aes(y = tr, x = da, fill = resposta, label = tr)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = pos), size=4) + 
  facet_wrap(~uf) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.direction="horizontal", 
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]